# Maze Generation with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, maze

I have been working on polishing my Ruby skills lately and came across a nice snazzy presentation on maze generation.

[Presentation by Jamis Buck](http://www.jamisbuck.org/presentations/rubyconf2011/index.html)

I would want to implement a couple of algorithms and then generate image files for the mazes.

I am quite unsure on the second part of the job: "generating image of the maze". I want a simple gem that lets me map my mazes to image.

Maybe sometime soon I would also want the whole thing as a Ruby on Rails application for the web.

How can I put all of it together?

Comment: Generating the image is the easy part.  I would checkout RMagick for starters, but there's probably other options as well.  Once you have your maze data, it should be easy enough to iterate through and output an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[chunky_png](https://github.com/wvanbergen/chunky_png) gem is definitely a thing that worth trying out.

Comment: Jamis actually used ChunkyPNG to create all the visualizations for his blog posts on this topic.

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy using RMagick:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'RMagick'

maze = <<-MAZE
##############
.............#
############.#
#............#
#.#.########.#
#.#..........#
#.############
MAZE

maze = maze.split("\n").map{|line| line.split('')}

square_size = 50

height = maze.size
width = maze.first.size

img_height = height * square_size
img_width = width * square_size

img = Magick::Image.new(img_width, img_height)

img_width.times do |col|
  img_height.times do |row|
    line_idx = (row/square_size).floor
    char_idx = (col/square_size).floor

    char = maze[line_idx][char_idx]

    color = (char == "#" ? "rgb(0, 0, 0)" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)")

    img.pixel_color(col, row, color)
  end
end

img.write('maze.png')
```

Answer (score 1):

Time moves on. Jamis Buck has now completed a book called 'mazes for programmers' on the pragmatic bookshelf. I think this is your go to reference for Ruby and Mazes.